# Changing branch length in dendrogram (pheatmap)

Tags: r, dendrogram, pheatmap

I am trying to plot a heatmap with the library pheatmap in R. 
I **think** that by default the branch length is proportional to the "dissimilarity" of the clusters that got merged at this step. I would like to chance that, so it is a fixed value because for my purpose it looks very weird!

If anyone has an idea how I can fix this, I would be very happy.

Here is a sample code

```
library(pheatmap)
test = matrix(rnorm(6000), 100, 60)
pheatmap(test)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Quite right: branch length indicates degree of dissimilarity. Not sure what you want to change about that. I doubt you can set the branch length to "a fixed value" because that would run against the very idea of cluster analysis. What exactly "looks weird" in the case of your data?

Comment: Thank you for confirming my assumption about the branch length!
In a nutshell, the last two clusters that i am merging show a very high dissimilarity, resulting in a very long branch which really messes up the viszualization, because the over branches are very short

Comment: I can't see how a discrepancy in length can "mess" up the visualization. Can you show a screen shot? Apart from that, would it help to adjust the `treeheight_col`argument? It defaults to 50; so if you want to elongate the branches choose a value > 50, if you want to shorten them, take a value < 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of two column groups with high dissimilarity:

```
library(pheatmap)
test = cbind(matrix(rnorm(3000), 100, 30),
            matrix(rnorm(3000)+10, 100, 30))
pheatmap(test)
```

[image]

TIn `pheatmap`the dendrogram is plotted by the `pheatmap:::draw_dendrogram` function
and branch lengths are stored in the `h` object.
Below I define equal-length branches adding the command 
 
`hc$height <- cumsum(rep(1/length(hc$height), length(hc$height)))`
as follows:

```
draw_dendrogram <- function(hc, gaps, horizontal = T) {
    # Define equal-length branches
    hc$height <- cumsum(rep(1/length(hc$height), length(hc$height)))
    h = hc$height/max(hc$height)/1.05
    m = hc$merge
    o = hc$order
    n = length(o)
    m[m > 0] = n + m[m > 0]
    m[m < 0] = abs(m[m < 0])
    dist = matrix(0, nrow = 2 * n - 1, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, 
        c("x", "y")))
    dist[1:n, 1] = 1/n/2 + (1/n) * (match(1:n, o) - 1)
    for (i in 1:nrow(m)) {
        dist[n + i, 1] = (dist[m[i, 1], 1] + dist[m[i, 2], 1])/2
        dist[n + i, 2] = h[i]
    }
    draw_connection = function(x1, x2, y1, y2, y) {
        res = list(x = c(x1, x1, x2, x2), y = c(y1, y, y, y2))
        return(res)
    }
    x = rep(NA, nrow(m) * 4)
    y = rep(NA, nrow(m) * 4)
    id = rep(1:nrow(m), rep(4, nrow(m)))
    for (i in 1:nrow(m)) {
        c = draw_connection(dist[m[i, 1], 1], dist[m[i, 2], 1], 
            dist[m[i, 1], 2], dist[m[i, 2], 2], h[i])
        k = (i - 1) * 4 + 1
        x[k:(k + 3)] = c$x
        y[k:(k + 3)] = c$y
    }
    x = pheatmap:::find_coordinates(n, gaps, x * n)$coord
    y = unit(y, "npc")
    if (!horizontal) {
        a = x
        x = unit(1, "npc") - y
        y = unit(1, "npc") - a
    }
    res = polylineGrob(x = x, y = y, id = id)
    return(res)
}
# Replace the non-exported function `draw_dendrogram` in `pheatmap`:
assignInNamespace(x="draw_dendrogram", value=draw_dendrogram, ns="pheatmap")

pheatmap(test)
```

The result is:

[image]