# Increasing left length branch in dendrogram (pheatmap)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, heatmap, dendrogram, pheatmap

I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713915/changing-branch-length-in-dendrogram-pheatmap/59772318#59772318) and I would like to got similar result plot. I am trying to plot a heatmap with the library pheatmap in R and I need to increase the left branch size. I would like to decrease the colored area and increase dendrogram branches. 
I found another [topic](https://slowkow.com/notes/pheatmap-tutorial/) that do a bit of what I need, but in that one, dendrogram is splitted from heatmap.
Here is a sample code:

`library(pheatmap)
 test = cbind(matrix(rnorm(3000), 100, 2), matrix(rnorm(3000)+10, 100, 2))
 pheatmap(test)
 pheatmap(test, cluster_cols = FALSE)`

[image]

Comment: Just `treeheight_row = 100`. (Please see its arguments by `?pheatmap `)

Comment: @cuttlefish44, it worked out of the box! Pretty well!